# Unusual GPU error when using ARCore, Unrecognised Android chroma siting range

Tags: android, arcore, mali

I'm receiving the error:

```
E/mali_winsys: Unrecognised Android chroma siting range: [2, 2]. Applying default
```

When opening my ArCore activities, any of them, using any range of models and textures.

For testing I'm using a S20 FE, the exynos version which has a Mali Gpu.
While this does not impede the activity to launch and work as intended, I thought it would be better to ask, and google wasn't my friend this time around.

Even using the absolute most barebones Arcore examples, I still receive the error.

Anyone else ever saw this?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing this error! It looks like ARCore is trying to use an invalid chroma sub-sample location that Mali doesn't understand.